# How can I get the span value under an a link tag? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to obtain the span value and make click in the div element?

I tried with the xpath only but that don't work.

My code:

```
xpath_cantidad_seguidos='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/div/span'
xpath_boton_seguidos='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/div'
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_cantidad_seguidos)))
    sleep(9)
    cantidad_seguidos=browser.find_element("xpath", xpath_cantidad_seguidos)
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_boton_seguidos)))
    button_seguidos=browser.find_element("xpath", xpath_boton_seguidos).click()
```

Web Code:

```html
<a class="x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz _a6hd" href="/fitvital.es/following/" role="link" tabindex="0"><div class="_aacl _aacp _aacu _aacx _aad6 _aade"><span class="_ac2a">98</span> seguidos</div></a>
```

Comment: Your question is missing minimal debugging details. We need to see the link to the page where these elements are and `xpath_cantidad_seguidos` and `xpath_boton_seguidos` values

Comment: I added that info.

Comment: Still missing the main information - the link to that page.

Comment: The page is my Instagram profile, but you need to see that like I see. Because with an other account the code of that element is diferent.

Comment: Again. How do you think we can debug this?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com you need to see Instagram like this: https://imgur.com/R1tjOjW